ASP.NET Core identity RoleManager.FindByNameAsync always returns null
Problem
I've seeded a few roles to my database and expect to be able to fetch them, but RoleManager returns null even though there exists a role with given name in my database.
The following line of code returns null:
var role = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync("SuperAdmin");

However I can get the role using its Id like this:
var x = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync("1");

How I added roles in first place? My database rows are:



Id
Name
NormalizedName
ConcurrencyStamp




1
SuperAdmin
SuperAdmin
Some guid string



I've added the Role using migrations like this:
public class RoleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(role => role.Name).HasMaxLength(50);

        builder.HasData(IdentitySeedDataProvider.GetDefaultRoles());
    }
}


What happens when you update the values in the NormalizedName column in the database to uppercase; so SUPERADMIN instead of SuperAdmin?

Your issue is likely due to a mismatch between the NormalizedName stored in the database and the RoleManager.FindByNameAsync method expects. When RoleManager.FindByNameAsync searches for a role by name, it normalizes the name internally before querying the database.
Given that the NormalizedName in your database is SuperAdmin, it should ideally be stored in an uppercase format, like SUPERADMIN, which is the default normalization behavior for role names.
so you can make your data like this
Id = "1", Name = "SuperAdmin", NormalizedName = "SUPERADMIN"

Your issue is likely due to a mismatch between the NormalizedName stored in the database and the RoleManager.FindByNameAsync method expects. When RoleManager.FindByNameAsync searches for a role by name, it normalizes the name internally before querying the database.
Given that the NormalizedName in your database is SuperAdmin, it should ideally be stored in an uppercase format, like SUPERADMIN, which is the default normalization behavior for role names. so you can make your data like this
Id = "1", Name = "SuperAdmin", NormalizedName = "SUPERADMIN",  ConcurrencyStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

